# Prompt for saving modified images

Tags: blend-files

Is there a way of seeing which modified images are unsaved?

I modified one image, packed it and saved it, and it's still warning me about saving one modified image. I'd like to know which image is supposedly unsaved and if it's the one I packed (and which doesn't have an asterisk), then why is that?

Edit: I might have saved it and then packed it so that's my bad, but I'd still like to know whether I can see a list of unsaved images somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images created in blender are not saved by default, nor are they packed in the file if they don't exist in a drive somewhere in your computer, you have to save them manually.

Unsaved images will show an asterisk on the top of the image viewer (or the UV editor)

[image]

To find unsaved images you can use the outliner.

Set it to Data API mode.

[image]

Expand the section for images.

If the image has not been saved the File Name section will be empty:

[image]

Saved images will show the path:

[image]

I'm sure that someone intelligent with coding skills, can come up with a script to automate finding which images lack a path and list them or save them...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not someone who's with intelligence but know how to code. I suffered same problem and wrote couple of line to find out which images are "dirty". Here is the code.

```
for image in bpy.data.images:
...     if image.is_dirty:
...         print(image.name)
...         print(image.filepath)
```

Put in "Python Console" on blender, it will spit out the name and file path of "dirty" images. I hope it will work for you too. I hope blender people implement better way to handle this problem :(

As you see, it's just a couple of script. I think they should put a list box in a dialogue and show us these information with warning...but we have a Python interpreter installed on blender so there's always some work arounds.